Using Sparse Categorical CrossEntropy, the loss becomes negative (tensorflow/keras)
I am doing the Tensorflow TF tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer) but with my own data. My data is not related to text, but it is sequences of tokens anyway, with a start token, and an end token. All the tokens go from 0 to 30 (start token is 31, end is 32). The lentgh of the sequence is 64 (in total 66 with the start and end tokens). A sequence looks like:
tf.Tensor(
[31 10 10 10 10 18 10 19 27 22  5 19 10 10 10 10 10 19 10 19 10  1  1 20
 22 15 12 26 14 22 17  3 10 14 22  9 25 25 20  7 19 28  4  7 15 14 13 25
 21 15 15 17 14 18 14 14 14 27 14 19 25 19  5  3 17 32], shape=(66,), dtype=int32)

My code is very similar to the one from the tutorial, with very small changes:
import pickle, os
 
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
 
from src.utils.callbacks import VQTransCallback
from src.models.layers import GlobalSelfAttention, CrossAttention, CausalSelfAttention
from src.models.layers import TransformerFeedForward as FeedForward
 
 
 
class PositionalEmbedding(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model):
        super().__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.embedding = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model, mask_zero=True) 
        self.pos_encoding = self.positional_encoding(length=66, depth=d_model)
 
    def compute_mask(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.embedding.compute_mask(*args, **kwargs)
 
    def positional_encoding(self, length, depth):
        depth = depth/2
        positions = np.arange(length)[:, np.newaxis]     # (seq, 1)
        depths = np.arange(depth)[np.newaxis, :]/depth   # (1, depth)
        angle_rates = 1 / (10000**depths)         # (1, depth)
        angle_rads = positions * angle_rates      # (pos, depth)
        pos_encoding = np.concatenate(
            [np.sin(angle_rads), np.cos(angle_rads)],
            axis=-1) 
        return tf.cast(pos_encoding, dtype=tf.float32)
 
    def call(self, x):
        length = tf.shape(x)[1]
        x = self.embedding(x)
        # This factor sets the relative scale of the embedding and positonal_encoding.
        x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))
        x = x + self.pos_encoding[tf.newaxis, :length, :]
        return x
 
 
class EncoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self,*, d_model, num_heads, dff, dropout_rate=0.1):
    super().__init__()
 
    self.self_attention = GlobalSelfAttention(
        num_heads=num_heads,
        key_dim=d_model,
        dropout=dropout_rate)
 
    self.ffn = FeedForward(d_model, dff)
    self.supports_masking = True
 
  def call(self, x):
    x = self.self_attention(x)
    x = self.ffn(x)
    return x
  
 
class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, *, num_layers, d_model, num_heads,
               dff, vocab_size, dropout_rate=0.1):
    super().__init__()
 
    self.d_model = d_model
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.pos_embedding = PositionalEmbedding(vocab_size=vocab_size, d_model=d_model)
 
    self.enc_layers = [
        EncoderLayer(d_model=d_model,
                     num_heads=num_heads,
                     dff=dff,
                     dropout_rate=dropout_rate)
        for _ in range(num_layers)]
    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
    self.supports_masking = True
 
  def call(self, x):
    x = self.pos_embedding(x)  # Shape `(batch_size, d_model)`.
    x = self.dropout(x)
    for i in range(self.num_layers):
      x = self.enc_layers[i](x)
    return x  # Shape `(batch_size, seq_len, d_model)`.
 
 
class DecoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, *, d_model, num_heads, dff, dropout_rate=0.1):
    super(DecoderLayer, self).__init__()
 
    self.causal_self_attention = CausalSelfAttention(
        num_heads=num_heads,
        key_dim=d_model,
        dropout=dropout_rate)
    self.cross_attention = CrossAttention(
        num_heads=num_heads,
        key_dim=d_model,
        dropout=dropout_rate)
    self.ffn = FeedForward(d_model, dff)
    self.supports_masking = True
 
  def call(self, x, context):
    x = self.causal_self_attention(x=x)
    x = self.cross_attention(x=x, context=context)
    x = self.ffn(x)  # Shape `(batch_size, seq_len, d_model)`.
    return x
  
 
class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, *, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, vocab_size,
               dropout_rate=0.1):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()
 
    self.d_model = d_model
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.pos_embedding = PositionalEmbedding(vocab_size=vocab_size, d_model=d_model)
    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
    self.dec_layers = [
        DecoderLayer(d_model=d_model, num_heads=num_heads,
                     dff=dff, dropout_rate=dropout_rate)
        for _ in range(num_layers)]
    self.supports_masking = True
 
  def call(self, x, context):
    x = self.pos_embedding(x)  # (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    for i in range(self.num_layers):
        x  = self.dec_layers[i](x, context)
    return x
 
 
class VQVAE2Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, *, enc_num_layers, dec_num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff,
                 vocab_size, codebook_length, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(num_layers=enc_num_layers, d_model=d_model,
                                num_heads=num_heads, dff=dff, vocab_size=vocab_size,
                                dropout_rate=dropout_rate)
        self.decoder = Decoder(num_layers=dec_num_layers, d_model=d_model,
                                num_heads=num_heads, dff=dff, vocab_size=vocab_size,
                                dropout_rate=dropout_rate)
        
        self.enc_num_layers = enc_num_layers
        self.dec_num_layers = dec_num_layers
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.dff = dff
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size + 3 + 1 # +3 start, end and mask
        self.codebook_length = codebook_length + 2 # +2 start and end tokens
 
        self.start_token = vocab_size+1
        self.end_token = vocab_size+2
 
        self.final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.vocab_size)
        self.supports_masking = True
 
 
    def call(self, inputs):
        enc_in, dec_in = inputs[0], inputs[1]
        
        context = self.encoder(enc_in)  # (batch_size, context_len, d_model)
        x = self.decoder(dec_in, context)  # (batch_size, target_len, d_model)
        # Final linear layer output.
        logits = self.final_layer(x)  # (batch_size, target_len, latent_size)
 
        try:
            # Drop the keras mask, so it doesn't scale the losses/metrics.
            # b/250038731
            del logits._keras_mask
        except AttributeError:
            pass
 
        # Return the final output and the attention weights.
        return logits
 
 
    def accuracy(self, label, pred):
        pred = tf.argmax(pred, axis=2)
        label = tf.cast(label, pred.dtype)
        match = label == pred
        match = tf.cast(match, dtype=tf.float32)
        return tf.reduce_sum(match) / self.codebook_length
 
 
    def compile_model(self):
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.AdamW()
        scce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
            from_logits=True)
 
        self.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                     loss=scce,
                     metrics=["accuracy"])
 
 
    def save_build(self, folder):
        """Saves the config before the training starts. The model itself will be saved
        later on using keras checkpoints.
 
        Args:
            folder: Where to save the config parameters
        """
        if not os.path.exists(folder):
            os.makedirs(folder)
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder, 'weights'))
 
        with open(os.path.join(folder, 'params.pkl'), 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump([
                self.enc_num_layers,
                self.dec_num_layers,
                self.d_model,
                self.num_heads,
                self.dff,
                self.vocab_size,
            ], f)
 
 
    def train_step(self, batch):
        """Processes one batch inside model.fit()."""
 
        enc_in, dec_in = batch[0][:,:66], batch[0][:,66:]
        dec_input = dec_in[:, :-1]
        dec_target = dec_in[:, 1:]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            preds = self([enc_in, dec_input])
            loss = self.compute_loss(None, dec_target, preds)
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
 
        # Update the metrics
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(dec_target, preds)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
 
 
    def test_step(self, batch):
        enc_in, dec_in = batch[0][:,:66], batch[0][:,66:]
        dec_input = dec_in[:, :-1]
        dec_target = dec_in[:, 1:]
        preds = self([enc_in, dec_input])
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(dec_target, preds)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
 
 
    def train(
        self, train_dataset, valid_dataset, epochs, run_folder, initial_epoch=0, 
        print_every_n_epochs=5
    ):
        
        test_batch = next(valid_dataset.dataset_iter)
        display_cb = VQTransCallback(test_batch, run_folder)
 
 
        checkpoint_filepath = os.path.join(
                run_folder, "weights/{epoch:03d}-{loss:.5f}-{val_loss:.5f}.weights.h5")
        checkpoint1 = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            checkpoint_filepath, save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True)
        checkpoint2 = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            os.path.join(run_folder, 'weights/last.weights.h5'),
            save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True)
 
        callbacks_list = [checkpoint1, checkpoint2, display_cb]
 
        self.fit(
            train_dataset.dataset, validation_data=valid_dataset.dataset,
            epochs=epochs, initial_epoch=initial_epoch, callbacks=callbacks_list,
            #steps_per_epoch=1000, validation_steps=1000
            )
 
    
    def generate(self, enc_in, dec_in, startid=0):
        """Performs inference over one batch of inputs."""
        bs = tf.shape(enc_in)[0]
 
        # scce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
        #     from_logits=True)
        # logits = self([enc_in, dec_in[:,:-1]])
        # print("SCCE LOSS")
        # print(scce(dec_in[:,1:],logits))
 
        if startid == 0:
            dec_in = tf.ones((bs, 1), dtype=tf.int32) * self.start_token
        else:
            dec_in = tf.cast(dec_in[:,:startid], dtype=tf.int32)
 
        for _ in range(self.codebook_length - startid):
            logits = self([enc_in, dec_in])
            logits = tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32)
            last_logit = tf.expand_dims(logits[:, -1], axis=-1)
            dec_in = tf.concat([dec_in, last_logit], axis=-1)
 
        return dec_in

I am using sparse cross entropy as in the tutorial.
I have a problem where the loss that is displayed as the training goes becomes negative. For example right now it says -2.0593.
I am using Sparse Cross Entropy. When I monitor  with a callback the loss of some test batches, the value returned is never negative, but usually some value between 1.5 and 2.
As you can see my last layer in the Transformer is a Dense layer without activation function (as in the tutorial) and therefore in the loss I set "from_logit=True". I have tried using a softmax activation in that last layer, and then setting "from_logit=False", but this does not seem to train, and it gets stuck in around a loss of 0.274, and it never moves.
I have no idea why the loss becomes negative, when the loss function always seems to output positive numbers when I test it.
Overall the results of the training are also not good.

All code has to be in the question as text, not as external links.

@Dr.Snoopy I have modified my question with the code.
